# how to set Increment id in foreach which under while function

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

here is my code

```
if (($handle = fopen("example.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    $row = 1;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
    {
         $prod_startid=1;
         foreach ($Prod_op_reindex as $size_op_key => $size_op_value) 
         {
            echo  $prod_startid;
         }

    }
}
```

i want $prod_startid can Increment in foreach
example: first time foreach the `$prod_startid` will be 1 2 3 4,

then after while function,in foreach the `$prod_startid` will be 5 6 7...

thanks everyone!

**update:**
the arrays not the same,because some array have empty value ,so i have to use array_values function,
for example:

Array ( [1] => XXS [2] => XS [3] => S [4] => M [5] => L [6] => XL [7] => XXL )

Array ( [1] => M [2] => L [3] => XL  )

Comment: You mean that your foreach will always fire 4 times?

Comment: @Mario Nikolaus no,all arrays not the same,i will  update my question later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you want this:

```
if (($handle = fopen("example.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
$row = 1;
$counter = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$prod_startid=$counter+1;
foreach ($Prod_op_reindex as $size_op_key => $size_op_value) {
   echo  $prod_startid;
    $prod_startid++;
    $couter = $prod_startid;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: my pleasure. However, i want you to look at @Mario's answers. i wrote this in a rush. his's actually improved and faster...

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
if (($handle = fopen("example.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  $row = 1;
  $prod_startid = 0;
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    foreach ($Prod_op_reindex as $size_op_key => $size_op_value) {
      $prod_startid++;
      echo $prod_startid;
    }
  }
}
```